# Extension-specific sessionStorage

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions, session-storage

I am creating a firefox addon that needs to store data on a per-tab basis.  I want to effectively mimic the normal `sessionStorage`, where data is preserved through page changes, does not interfere with other tabs, and is deleted when the tab is closed.  In particular, this data is preserved through browser restarts.

However, I cannot use `sessionStorage` because I do not wish to interfere with any scripts that may be running on the page itself; if I store my data under the key `foo` and a webpage happens to use the key `foo`, then interference will occur.  I could use a UUID as my key, but that will still interfere if the page iterates over the `sessionStorage` keys.

Unfortunately, I cannot simply store a mapping `{ tab.id -> my data }`, because tab ids can change when the browser restarts (I tested it).

Is there any way to persistently store tab-specific data in a firefox extension, such that it cannot interfere with the content of the tab?

Comment: See [browser.sessions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/sessions) API.

Comment: Aaand there's a tool for this specifically.  Not sure what I was expecting.  Thank you!  If you make an answer I'll accept it.